# Relative path for static files in Expressjs or Koajs

Tags: node.js, express, koa

I have a Structure for my application similar to below :

- ApplicationA

  - a.js
- ApplicationB

  - b.js
- ApplicationC

  - c.js
- public

i have some static file in `public` directory . how can application `a.js` that located in `ApplicationA` directory access to `public` directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var path = require("path")

var target = "../public/"

var resolved = path.relative(__dirname, target)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to go up a directory? If so use `../` to go up a directory from where you are so for instance if `ApplicationA` and `public` are in the same directory you could use:

```
../public/filename.file
```

Comment: there are not in the same directory .